# how to write an empty line in file from a variable?

Tags: windows, command-line

In Windows Command Line I normally write empty line in a file with

```
echo; >> file
```

However, what I have now is a variable

```
$param1%
```

If I want echo to write it in the file I have to do

```
echo %param1% >> file
```

**HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM START :**

If I'd like an empty like I'd make

```
set param1=;
```

However since the `;` is not in contact with the echo word the command is

```
echo ; >> file
```

which write the `;` in the file...

I need the variable to sometime contains text, and sometime nothing. How can I do it?

Comment: `if  "%param1%"=="" echo;>>file else echo %param1%>>file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if  "%param1%"=="" echo;>>file else echo %param1%>>file`

Answer (score 1):

If a `param1` variable does not exist (the same as `set "param1="`), then `%param1%` results to:

- **In a `.bat` script**: `%param1%` results to an empty string (a string of zero length);
- **In a CLI window**: `%param1%` results to the `%param1%` string.

*In a `.bat` script* use (note no spaces surrounding `%param1%`)

```
>> file (echo;%param1%)
```

*In a CLI window* use

```
>>file (if not defined param1 (echo;) else echo;%param1%)
```

**Note proper using of parentheses** in `if`-`else`! For instance, check interesting result of next command:

```
if  ""=="" echo;"THEN branch">>file else echo;"ELSE branch">>file
```

Output:

```
==>if  ""=="" echo;"THEN branch">>file else echo;"ELSE branch">>file

==>type file
"THEN branch" else echo;"ELSE branch"
```